# H.264 codec explained

Tags: algorithm, video, video-streaming, video-processing, h.264

I am making a app which supports video calls and I am looking for a tutorial/doc explaining the structure of the h.264 codec. I want to be able to package the stream, wrap it in datagrams, send and unpack on the receiving side.

Any suggestions/reading materials?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What do you mean by structure? If you are talking about the bitstream syntax, you can download the [H.264 standard](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264/en) for free. There are also many books/papers about H.264 such as the one by [Iain Richardson](http://www.vcodex.com/h264.html).

If you are more interested in the network transport of H.264 over IP, why don't you use the [RTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) standard and associated [payload format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984)?

Comment: I am more interested in the RTP packaging process. I am making a video streaming app on blackberry and I have access to the video stream and I need to be able to package it in RTP packs in a correct way that it could be used properly on the receiving end regardless of datagram loss.  So thanks these links seem exactly what I need. One last thing - does a video file with h.264 encoded video have a header? I mean when i record in a file with h.264 encoding it saves the video in a .3gp file format and there seems to be a header at the beginning of the file - where can I read about this?

Comment: You can find that in the 3GPP specification: AFAICT it looks like it could be the following one but double check that: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/26244.htm Otherwise search under http://www.3gpp.org/specifications. Keep in mind that the .3gp file is just a container format (in your case one used on mobile phones) and has nothing to do with the network packetization. Also, you might need/be able to read the H.264 SPS and PPS somewhere in the header. It could be important for you to extract that info.

Answer (score 6):

Here is very basic principles of [H.264](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264-202108-I/en/wp_h264_31669_en_0803_lo.pdf)

If you are writing an application for network cameras, RTP is what you are looking for.
And If you are implementing it in C++, there is [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) library would choose.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [x264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264) which is an existing implementation of the codec. You might even want to consider using that codec rather than implementing [AVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) from scratch.