# Is there an open source H.264 implementation on FPGA?

Tags: h.264, fpga, vlsi, soc

I want to design and implement an H.264 baseline/main profile encoder on FPGA for real-time HD video processing. To begin with, I am looking for design examples that would help me to understand the H.26 implementation on FPGA. Therefore, is there any open source project for this? I tried to search on Github, but found only [one](https://github.com/bcattle/hardh264) repository.

Anybody who knows some information about this, please help me!

And provide some information about:

- What are the essential technical skills required?
- What is the best way to implement this?

As far as I know, we can write RTL-only codes or implement by HW/SW co-design.

But I have no idea about what are the differences, what is better.

Answer (score 2):

---

**Question 1**:

*What are the essential technical skills required?*

---

**Answer**:
H.264 is a highly used video coding standard. The complete standard is a family of specifications covering a variety of encoding/decoding features, resolutions, and frame rates. So initially you need to understand the fundamentals of the standard. You need to understand how H.264 encoder and decoder works. May be this [reference](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2847263.2847274) can help you to start with H.264 fundamentals from FPGA's point of view. You can also go through the [H.264 codec explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795054/h-264-codec-explained).

---

**Question 2**:

*What is the best way to implement this? As far as I know, we can write RTL-only codes or implement by HW/SW co-design.*

---

**Answer**:
Although preferably one should write the main design called [RTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/register-transfer-level/info) in a hardware description language (HDL) namely [Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/verilog/info) or [VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vhdl/info). Because most FPGA compilers expect to be given a design description in RTL form. RTL is an acronym for *register transfer level*. This means that your Verilog or VHDL code describes how data is transformed as it is passed from register to register.

However, it's plan *wrong* to say that you can only implement H.264 design (your H.264 RTL) in VHDL or Verilog. You can even write your H.264 design in C/C++ and use a [compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vivado-hls/info) to generate your RTL in Verilog and VHDL. Below is code snippet of a simple H.264 decoder written in plain C that can be [synthesized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synthesis) on almost any FPGA.

```
void decode_main(NALU_t* nalu, 
                 StorablePicture pic[MAX_REFERENCE_PICTURES], 
                 StorablePictureInfo pic_info[MAX_REFERENCE_PICTURES]) {


#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none register port=nalu->startcodeprefix_len
#pragma HLS RESOURCE core=AXI4LiteS variable=nalu->startcodeprefix_len
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none register port=nalu->len
#pragma HLS RESOURCE core=AXI4LiteS variable=nalu->len
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none register port=nalu->nal_unit_type
#pragma HLS RESOURCE core=AXI4LiteS variable=nalu->nal_unit_type
#pragma HLS INTERFACE ap_none register port=nalu->nal_reference_idc

  // optimization pragmas continue//

 extern seq_parameter_set_rbsp_t SPS_GLOBAL;
 extern pic_parameter_set_rbsp_t PPS_GLOBAL;
 extern ImageParameters img_inst;
 extern slice_header_rbsp_t sliceHeader_inst;
 extern char intra_pred_mode[PicWidthInMBs*4][FrameHeightInMbs*4];
 
 // below rest of the code continues//
}
```

If you see, it has explicit compiler specific optimizations as `HLS pragmas`. That actually means [High-Level Synthesis (HLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_synthesis) optimizations. On Stackoverflow (SO) seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is rightly not appreciated. Only to help you understand that you can still implement H.264 design apart from HDLs like Verilog or VHDL and since I have given you a brief explanation of my own, you can go through the complete design [here](https://github.com/adsc-hls/synthesizable_h264) for your further understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response.
I never thought about the HLS.
But I wonder if the synthesized design can work as fast as the RTL design.

Comment: If I write the H.264 encoder in C/C++ and compile it using HLS, is it possible to meet the time and resource requirements for a real-time HD encoder?

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help! My experience with HLS suggests that a HLS synthesized IP core can be as fast as RTL if you have efficiently transformed the code with the right HLS compiler optimizations. And your second question if  it is possible to meet the time and resource requirements for a real-time HD encoder? Of course it is possible. You can read the reference I have shared. They achieve a performance close to hand coded RTL for a real-time HD decoder. I have  worked on HLS based designs and my experience says you achieve  resource and timing requirements if developed efficiently.

Comment: During citation, I find that there are actually more projects that implemented the H.264 decoder than H.264 encoder even with the HLS.
Is it so difficult to implement a real-time HD video encoder running on FPGA?

Comment: H.264 is a complex design. Even decoder is no less complex. Similarly , you can implement encoder on HLS. as well.  You can also check this [resource](http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/) as well for open encoder-decoder.